# How do I override the view field?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to override taxonomy term view views-view-field.html.twig to style the list of taxonomy term content.

I can't seem to find what the correct override is. My debug suggestions are not suggesting anything.

I have tried:

```
views-view-fields--taxonomy-term--%.html.twig
views-view-fields--taxonomy-term.html.twig
```

What is the correct template name to target the views-view-fields of the taxonomy term view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
views-view-fields--taxonomy-term.html.twig
```

This is the correct template suggestion. For it to work however, the default taxonomy view must be configured to render the content as fields rather than as the content its self.